# How to use mmcli to send sms?

Tags: usb, modem, sms

As questions says, I want to send sms using mmcli.
As ubuntu already has mmcli installed, I connected my phone via USB, enabled USB debugging(I also enabled usb tethering but I don't know if that is necessary) but mmcli still cant recognize it as modem.
Can anyone tell me what am I missing? I am a total newbie at this topic so any obvious things that I may have not done, please do tell :)
Phone is LG Leon and using Ubuntu 16.04(GNOME, but I don't think that is relevant :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is that an Android phone will never be recognized as a modem because it doesn't allow the PC direct access to hardware inside the phone. What you get is just a connection to the operating system on the phone which then in turn handles communications with the modem.

If you just want to take advantage of the full-size keyboard on your PC when sending SMS, there are several apps out there for this purpose. I myself use one called Airdroid, but there are plenty of options out there. Details of each app differ, but the basic principle is that the phone runs a small web server which you can access in the PC browser to send messages and do some other things.